# How can I make my text responsive for any screen flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, text, responsive, textfield

How can I make my `Text` responsive for any screen in flutter.
I have 3 `Text` and `Textfields` and I want to make it responsive to any screen size.
By the way I have tried to use `Flexible` and I put them inside a `Container` that I put it inside a `Row`.
But when I try it on my mobile phone it look super nice and on another phone it look so bad and big.

Comment: can you please share sample code as well as screenshots ?

Comment: THIS IS MY CODE

Answer (score 0):

have you checked auto_size_text on pub.dev ?
i have used it twice , and works perfectly here is the link [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)